# Oracle database: bulk update generate ORA-01779

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to update on bulk all hardcoded values in a table with value from another table on an Oracle database.

**Table Request**

- request_id
- service_assigned
- client_id

**Table User**

- user_id
- service

**Table lnk_request_user**

- assignee_id (link to user_id from user table)
- request_id

```
        update
        (
        select req.SERVICE_ASSIGNED as OLD, users.service as NEW
            from REQUEST req, LNK_REQUEST_ASSIGNEE assignees, USER users
            where
                req.request_id = assignees.request_id
                and
                users.user_id = assignees.assignee_id
                and
                req.client_id=9999         
        ) request 
        set request.OLD = request.NEW;
```

Oracle return:

> SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non
> key-preserved table

What's does it means? How can I fix my query?

Comment: "set request.OLD = request.NEW" , you try to assign a retrieved value to... another retrieved value... should be "set COLUMN_NAME =  request.NEW"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a merge like below:

```
merge into REQUEST tgt
using (
  select req.request_id, users.service SERVICE_ASSIGNED
  from REQUEST req, LNK_REQUEST_ASSIGNEE assignees, USER users
  where req.request_id = assignees.request_id
    and users.user_id = assignees.assignee_id
    and req.client_id=9999           
) src
on (tgt.request_id=src.request_id)
when matched then update set
  tgt.SERVICE_ASSIGNED=src.SERVICE_ASSIGNED;
```